# How to fix "0" number missing when converting array to csv using javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

Try to convert array to csv file using Javascript.

But when phone number value convert to csv , the 0 number is missing at the beginning of the letter

```
const rows = [
    ["David", "08545456"],
    ["Anna", "082245544"]
];

let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

rows.forEach(function(rowArray) {
    let row = rowArray.join(",");
    csvContent += row + "\r\n";
});

var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

link.click()
```

But the csv file looks as shown in the screenshot:

[csv result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuw9d.png)

How to send the exact number ?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `let row = rowArray.map(x => \`"${x}"\`).join(",");` This surrounds all CSV cell data with quotes, preserving the content. edit: excel still screws up

Comment: Apparently you can save the file as .txt instead, then import it into excel and "fix" the issue that way. Not very convenient obviously.

Comment: You can try this `const rows = [
    ["David", '="08545456"'],
    ["Anna", '="08545456"']
];`

Comment: @angel.bonev this works, i've used it a couple of times for the same issue as op.

Comment: Excel will change it. Importing the data as suggested by @ChrisG can solve it though. But rest assured if you are reading the csv in any program/tool zeros are preserved. It is the problem of display in excel.